# Can Alexa app display BodyTemplate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, aws-sdk-nodejs

I build my custom skill with some Bodytemplate. However they could not be displayed on Alexa app or Simulator. I am using BodyTemplate2Builder. Thanks.

Comment: This question is liable to downvotes since you didn't provide any MCVE attempt or code to clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Alexa app does not seem to support display.

However, it is possible to test Alexa App displays on the test simulator provided in the Alexa Skills Kit.

You have to first enable the Display Interface for your skill. Do this buy going to the Interface Option (available in the left panel) in the Build Tab in your Alexa Skills Kit.

[image : how to enable display interface for testing (Build tab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLdAZ.png)

Now build your skill and go to the Test tab. Select the Echo Show Display and/or Echo Spot Display checkboxes (available on top of the testing page), depending on which Echo you want to simulate your skill on.

[image : enable display output for testing (Test tab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne9WJ.png)

After this, you can test your skill normally, and the display outputs will be displayed! Scroll down on the right panel to see the display(s).

[image : scroll down to see the display output (Test tab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuZHi.png)

You can test any BodyTemplate or ListTemplate this way.